# Preventing Google from translating the header and footer of my Wordpress page

Tags: html, wordpress, google-translate

When someone tries to translate my website with google, they end up translating important aspects of the header and footer like the email, and even breaking the page. How do I avoid this?

I read that I can use the class="notranslate" attribute, but I don't know where to embed it using wordpress. Also, the tag should only affect the header and footer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+class%3D%22notranslate%22&newwindow=1 yet?  In any case, knowing Wordpress, if you do find a way to fix it, it might break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this trick, with Elementor free edition.
Used this for the Menu (Header), activate the CSS Class from WP Screen Options, at the top of WP Dash
[Enable CSS Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNrhD.jpg)
[Menu add class NOTRANSLATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTTJM.jpg)

For the FOOTER, use this
[Every widget have this field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9430h.jpg)
Remember I used Elementor, free...

Hope You have found this a useful solution, for Me is working...
For the title site use this code taken from internet:
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].setAttribute('class', 'notranslate');

You can try to place it in GTranslate plugin settings Widget Code section.
The last box....below

Anto